# How to use named range with offset function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

i have created named range using the offset function but i want to show all the lists in my named range in cell A1. The named range is dynamic, i can have 5 item or 10 items but i always want to display whatever items i have in the named range in the first column.  How would i do this?  I have tried to use the offset function but i always get the first item only and i want to show all the items that i have in my named range. i have tried and researched but could not find solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow exactly what you want to do but here is one method.

If your named range is something like this:

[image]

And you want to display this in Col A, enter the following formula in A1 and drag down.

```
=MYRANGE
```

---

Column A output:

[image]

---

If your range is dynamic and you don't want to show an error, modify the equation to look like this:

=IFERROR(MYRANGE,"")

Below is the result.  Column A has the new equation down to row 7 and column B has the first equation to show the error.

[image]

Comment: The OFFSET does nothing that just entering =MYRANGE would not do in the same way.

Comment: @teylyn your right, I was caught up in something else and overlooked that.  I edited the post to correct.  Thanks